# Software to visually represent telecommunications networks

Tags: visual-c++, graphics, mfc, topology

I am working on some software tools used for the design and optimization of telecoms networks: routing, capacity allocation and topology.

To represent the network nodes and interconnecting links I currently use standard MFC calls to draw things like lines and ellipses using mouse clicks, menu commands and so on.

For the time being this has been an adequate means of graphically representating what the 
network looks like, as I have been more concerned with getting the underlying algorithms right, improving efficiencies and so on.

At some stage I will want to improve the look and feel of the software.  Is anyone aware of any GUI software that is particularly suited to this purpose, open source or otherwise, that would be suitable for the network building stage?  The intention is to use something that is more slick than what I am currently doing, especially when it comes to (say) dragging nodes into the drawing area and setting their properties. Also of interest would be graphics to display bar charts representing link utilization levels.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

For looks, I think you must go for WPF. But the migration from MFC wont be that easy if you have a huge code base. Although GDI is said to be good, performance wise.